# Spatial join to isolate clusters

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I have this shp made by many tiny polygons. I want to identify clusters (red circles) with a spatial join and then apply a `minimum bounding geometry` to isolate them with a perimeter.

[image: my shp]

I am having troubles with the spatial join. I tried to put this shp as target and join feature and apply a `closest` with 10m radius.

In my output in the distance field I have only 0s. I tried with more values but same result.

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

1 Convert your polygon to points with **Feature to point**

2 [Density-based Clustering](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/densitybasedclustering.htm#L_) with DBScan method, min feature per cluster=2, and search distance=10. You will probably need to adjust the distance a few times.

3 Spatial join the output attributes to the input polygons, for example the Cluster_ID attribute.

4 Minimum bounding geometry Convex hull, group by Cluster_ID

5 Select geometries where Cluster_ID>-1

[image]